# Remove all traffic for a specific user agent

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way to exclude, from **all properties and all views** of Google Analytics, the visitors with a **specific user agent**?

Note: it's not for spam/bot prevention (I already checked the feature *Admin > View settings > Bot filtering > Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders*), it's to remove a part of own traffic. I can't use IP filtering because my IP changes all the time, and I use many devices (mobile/desktop/laptop). I also can't use cookies, because often I want to test my website **as a random non-logged user**. I didn't find anything even after exploring deeply the Analytics UI. Maybe this requires API ?

Comment: Why don't you take a different tack and look at browser plugins that block the GA tracking code?

Comment: @MikeSullivan Good idea indeed, I'd like to test this! Unfortunately, [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/no-google-analytics/) has a poor review, and users report some problems. Do you know one that is good?

Comment: I can recommend Ghostery https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/ghostery/. You can deactivate Google Analytics and every other tracker with this.

Comment: @DanielS: seems cool, but not available for my Firefox 47. It requires FF57+, but latest stable release is 54...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(Google Tag Manager seemed a bit labyrinthic for me.)

I finally did this:

- Use [Custom UserAgent String](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-useragent-string/) extension (available for FF and Chrome) and set UserAgent to `NoTracking` (you can do it specifically for certain websites, i.e. your websites only, see options).
- Add this in the PHP page, in the Analytics Javascript part:

  ```
  <?php  if ($_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] === 'NoTracking') echo 'if (false)'; ?>
  ```

  It looks like this:

  ```
  <script>
  <?php  if ($_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] === 'MyselfXYZ12') echo 'if (false)'; ?>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)}) window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  <script>
  ```

  This will have the effect of disabling the creation of `ga` object for your traffic only.

NB: I first thought about disabling GA code for my own traffic via Javascript with `if (navigator.userAgent == 'NoTracking')` but it seems that the UserAgent change thanks to the extension "Custom UserAgent String" has effect *only after the page is rendered*, which is too late.

Answer (score 2):

In the first step you have to get the User Agent into Google Analytics. You can do this with the Tag Manager, by creating a `custom Javascipt`. This can return the User Agent and you can send it to GA with a custom Dimension or a Event. (It´s also possible to do this without the GTM).

1. Log in to the Tag Manager and navigate to Variables
2. Now we have to add a Javascript Variable. The User Agent is stored in the `navigator.userAgent` property

[image]

3. Now we have to push this data into the Google Analytics Account. We could do this with a custom Dimension or a Event. In this example we take a Event. As Action we send the Page Path - you don´t have to do this, but maybe it´s helpfull later for some reports. As a Trigger we define "All Pages" so the event is fired with every pageview. The User Agent we send as a Event Label.

[image]

If you have this information in GA you can add a filter on Account Level (for alle Views and Propertys).
Filter Type = Custom > Select the Event or Dimension > Type the User Agent to exclude.

We can see the User Agent of the Users visited our site now in GA Behavior > Events > Top Events > Search for the Event Category (namend in Tag Manager (in our case "User Agent"))

[image]

In the last step we exclude the User Agent from all our Propertys and Views.
Admin > All Filters (In the Account column) > "+ Add Filter" > Filter Type = Custom > Exclude > Select "Event Label" in the Dropdown > specify the User Agent to ignore

[image]

Select the Views, there this User Agent should be ignored > DONE

Comment: Thanks! Can you add details / screenshots? I currently don't know about these Tag manager, Dimension, Event, etc. You say we need Tag manager, and then that it's possible without GTM. Thanks in advance for more details I think it could help many people !

Comment: **The event method will not work.** GA Filters work on a per-hit basis so this approach will only filter out the extra user-agent event, without filtering out any other tracking. The custom dimension approach would work, as that can apply to all hits.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't directly answer the question of how to block a user by user-agent string, it does I think solve the problem of how to remove your own personal traffic from being counted by Google Analytics

Google created a chrome plugin:

**Google Analytics Opt-out Add-on (by Google)**
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-opt-out/fllaojicojecljbmefodhfapmkghcbnh

(Does require a chromium-based browser and appears you're using firefox but may help other users. Interestingly, there does appear to be a link which will download an xpi extension file if accessed from Firefox, but I'm not too sure about it https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout )

For Firefox, I believe this one can block Google Analytics traffic:

**uBlock Origin**
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/