# Don't track the visit with GoogleAnalytics if specific User Agent

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, user-agent

**How to disable GoogleAnalytics Javascript tracking code if the user agent is `UserAgentXUI765DQZ`?**

Is this good practice or bad:

```
<script>

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxxx-7', 'auto');
  if (navigator.userAgent != "UserAgentXUI765DQZ")  // addition here
      ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

---

Context:

I don't have a static IP, and my goal is to **not-track my own traffic on Google Analytics**. These solutions don't fit my needs:

1. visiting my website only as logged => no, I really want to see how normal visitors see my website
2. visiting my website only from http://internaltraffic.example.com instead of http://www.example.com => same reason than 1. + sometimes you forget, you follow a link and end up as http://www.example.com
3. Google Tag Manager, a bit labyrinthic for me

For this, I have set up a custom UserAgent "UserAgentXUI765DQZ" in Firefox and Chrome thanks to [this exension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-useragent-string/).

But then I noticed that [filtering out the traffic from a specific user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44634482/1422096) is tricky in Google Analytics, it requires Tag Manager, and to do multiple steps, that I would have to repeat for every website (every Property) of Google Analytics, etc.

That's why I decided to modify the GA `<script></script>` to not track the specific user agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with adding conditionals within the provided Google Analytics snippet. I do it all the time to set custom dimensions prior to sending the pageview.

The only thing you will be lacking with that method is the ability to test using that browser. Best practices are to have an unfiltered view for testing as well as a filtered view for actual reporting. By preventing the pageview, you will not track *any* of your own traffic.

My personal thought would be to use a custom dimension and set up the filtered view to not include any traffic if the custom dimension matches. Then you can switch over to your unfiltered view for testing.

To answer your question

> Is this good practice or bad

I wouldn't say there is anything inherently wrong with that; it'll do what you're trying. I would just personally approach it slightly different (albeit more time consuming to setup if you manage hundreds of websites).

**Edit**: To implement a custom dimension, first you need to define it within Google Analytics Admin (Under "Custom Definitions > Custom Dimensions" in the Properties column). I would set this one to the scope of "User".

Then right before you send the pageview, add the following code:

```
//...
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxxx-7', 'auto');
if (navigator.userAgent == "UserAgentXUI765DQZ"){
    ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Internal User'); //Make sure "dimension1" matches what Google generated. You can change "Internal User" to anything you'd like.
}
ga('send', 'pageview');
//...
```

Then, back in Google Analytics Admin in the Views column, add a Filter that excludes traffic that matches your custom dimension. Make sure you do this on a new view otherwise (like I mentioned above) you won't be able to test yourself.

Comment: Thanks @GreatBlakes. Can you give details how to achieve this `My personal thought would be to use a custom dimension and set up the filtered view to not include any traffic if the custom dimension matches. Then you can switch over to your unfiltered view for testing.`? How to create such a dimension (in anlaytics JS code? somewhere else?). Where to filter it in GA (which menu?). 
PS: Does it require GoogleTagManager? (If possible I'd like to avoid another (n+1)th layer)

Comment: Something else: what is the effect of keeping  `ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxxx-7', 'auto');` but not sending `ga('send', 'pageview')`?

Comment: I've added more info about how to make the custom dimension. Also, you make a good point of- if you keep the `create` function, but don't trigger the `pageview`, you will still trigger events which will add `(not set)` landing page data to your reports (which will make your metrics count incorrect). You'll also be loading the analytics.js for no reason- which would slow down your websites.